# jQuery call external plugin method from inside another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm using a jQuery carousel plugin with no documentation and Lazy Load XT (https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt).

By default, Lazy Load XT only loads images on the following events: `load` `orientationchange` `resize` `scroll`.

I'd like the carousel plugin to lazy load the images when `switchSlide` method is called, but am having trouble implementing it.

The 2 ideas I had in approaching the issue are:

1. Manually initialize Lazy Load XT each time `switchSlide` method is called from the Carousel.
2. Somehow pass a custom event from the Carousel plugin to the Lazy Load XT `updateEvent` option

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is it possible to call an external method / initialize a plugin (e.g, Lazy Load XT) from inside a plugin?
2. Is it possible to call Lazy Load XT from within the carousel plugin's `switchSlide` method to force the images to display? If so, how?
3. Is it possible to pass a custom event from the Carousel plugin to the Lazy Load XT `updateEvent` option? If so, how?

**CAROUSEL PLUGIN CODE**

http://jsfiddle.net/amc/vfekeyey/

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you listen for `$(document).on('switchSlide', doSomething);` where the function `doSometing` triggers the event you want Lazy Load XT to execute?

Comment: When I attempted to implement this code, the console throws a "switchSlide is not defined" error. I'm not sure if `switchSlide` is a public method or not.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I thought switchSlide was an event being fired it's a function being called I assume. I'll review further.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are correct, `switchSlide` is a function. From what I can tell it is a private function. Line 366 in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Honestly the only way I can see doing this is to modify the code for each plugin and fire custom events at the specific functions and listen for them in your own code. Then you can act upon it. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: @gautsch thank you so much for taking the time to help, I appreciate it!